# Open Chrome window behind all opened windows using CLI

Tags: command-line, google-chrome, chromium

I am using automated testing with Nightwatch + Selenium + Chrome. And since I am testing a WebRTC app I am opening multiple windows and switching them from one to another in tests frequently. This is very annoying when developing, because windows just continuously popping up while tests are running on top of my active windows.

Is there any way (perhaps CLI switch) to open them behind all windows or something like that?

I also don't want to use headless chrome because I sometimes need to see what is happening in browser, open dev tools etc.

Answer (score 0):

You may easily keep these windows out of sight by running your tests on another
virtual desktop. You may switch desktops using the Task View button or by
the hotkeys <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Left/Right</kbd>.

For Windows, you may consult these references:

- [Microsoft -  Multiple desktops in Windows 10](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4028538/windows-10-multiple-desktops)
- [How to use multiple desktops in Windows 10](https://www.howtogeek.com/197625/how-to-use-virtual-desktops-in-windows-10/)

[image]